# Add an event listener to the window

Tags: dom, reason, bs-webapi

I am trying to add an event listener to the window, but I am unsure how to get the window.

I currently have this.

```
let onUnhandledRejection = (e) => {
  /* TODO: write this */
}

WindowRe.addEventListener(
  "unhandledrejection",
  onUnhandledRejection,
  WINDOW_GOES_HERE: Dom.window
);
```

Comment: This explains it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: the `window` object? It's in global scope.

Answer (score 1):

The current window object is available as `Webapi.Dom.window`

```
let onUnhandledRejection = (e) => {
  /* TODO: write this */
}

Webapi.Dom.Window.addEventListener(
  "unhandledrejection",
  onUnhandledRejection,
  Webapi.Dom.window
);
```

You also shouldn't use `WindowRe` as it's a private API.

Comment: Note that `Dom` (without `Webapi.` in front) is a module that ships with `bs-platform` that contains most of the types used by `Webapi`. This can be a bit confusing, but we'll hopefully be a bit smarter about naming things in the future.